# Does sched_setscheduler() /sched_getscheduler() only affect scheduling policy of the specified process and its child processes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

I am confused about how `sched_setscheduler()` works in Linux.

My understanding is Linux uses `CFS (SCHED_NORMAL)` internally for kernel processes scheduling. When user space starts a program (process), a `clone()` call would be trigged to create a corresponding scheduling entity in kernel space.

So assume there are user process A and process B. 
Process A calls `sched_setscheduler(pid_A, SCHED_RR)` and spawns child processes A1, A2. 
Process B calls `sched_setscheduler(pid_B, SCHED_NORMAL)` and spawns child processes B1, B2.

How would Linux schedule process A and B in this case as they are using different scheduling policy?  Does Linux still uses its internal default scheduling policy to choose between A and B, but leave A, A2, A1 compete each other using `SCHED_RR` and B, B1, B2 with `SCHED_NORMAL` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel has a series of "scheduling classes" which are modules that decide what thread should run when a core goes idle.

Since `SCHED_RR` is a real-time scheduling class, it will get to decide what to schedule onto an idle core before `SCHED_NORMAL` does. That means that in some sense, A and its children have strict priority over B and its children.

However, I believe Linux reserves something like 5% CPU for non-realtime scheduling classes, so B and its children should not be starved of CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In case both process A and B set their policy to same category but different class (for example, A sets SCHED_FIFO and B sets SCHED_RR), how would linux kernel determine which one has high priority?

Comment: @keye, I think it would look at the [priority value](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Priorities_and_policies.html), but you might have to look at the source to determine which of them gets to run first if the threads are at the same priority value. I haven't found any references in a quick search.